# Calculate the arc length of the curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the arc length of the curve
$$  \overrightarrow r (t) = 〈 −t \sin t − \cos t, −t^2 , t \cos t − \sin t 〉$$ , between the points $(-1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, -π^2 , −π)$.

I did this exercise, but I got stuck in this part. How do I know which values I should use to replace?

$$  \overrightarrow r'(t) = 〈 −t \cos t , 2t , -t \sin t 〉$$
$$  \overrightarrow r'(t) = ( (−t \cos t)^2 + (2t)^2 + (-t \sin t)^2 )$$
$$  \overrightarrow r'(t) = \sqrt{t^2\cos^2t + 4t + t^2\sin^2t}$$
$$L=\int_a^b \begin{Vmatrix} r'(t)\end{Vmatrix} $$
$$L=\int_0^π\sqrt{(\cos t-\cos t+t\sin t)^2+(2t)^2+(-\sin t+\sin t+t\cos t)^2 \, dt } = \int_0^π\sqrt{5t^2} \, dt=π^2\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} $$

Comment: $\vec{r}'(t)$ should be a vector-valued function, i.e., for a fixed $t$, $\vec{r}'(t)$ is a vector.

Comment: The result is $$\pi\sqrt {5} $$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\vec{r}\,'(t)=\langle -t\cos t,-2t,-t\sin t\rangle$$ we have
$$\left\|\vec{r}\,'(t)\right\|=\sqrt{t^2\cos^2t+4t^2+t^2\sin^2t}=\sqrt{5t^2}=\sqrt{5}\,t\qquad\text{for}\;\;0\le t\le \pi$$